# How to align multiple items in CSS column

Tags: css

I am struggling to make the individual box titles line up, and hence their position within the box changes with the length.

I am currently using a grid with 3 columns and they all have the same height. However the text is placing itself in the middle and if I change it to

```
align-items: start;
```

then I have uneven height columns but everything is lined up

How can I make sure my icons and sub title are always lined up? I have attached some pictures and the code:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Next time, paste your html and css here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the align-items: start; and add flex-grow: 1; to the cards.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be easier if we could copy your HTML and CSS to play around with, but my initial thought would be to try wrapping your `<h1>` and `<p>` in a new div, and then add height (try using 'min-height') and width values to that new div.

That way the logos are forced to sit above the text div regardless of the amount of text below them.